# Angular Router UI Child Controller not Starting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the route definition below if I go to #/systemadmin/edit/Testing it brings up the SystemAdminController but not the one defined in the child route I am using. I am missing something.

```
 $stateProvider.state('systemadmin', { url: '/systemadmin', controller: 'SystemAdminController', templateUrl: 'app/templates/SystemAdmin.html?v=' + dl.buildDate })
        .state('systemadmin.edituser', { url: '/edit/:selectedUser', controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) { debugger; }, templateUrl: 'app/templates/SystemAdmin.html?v=' + dl.buildDate });
```

Comment: Well what do you mean by brings up? The parent controller will execute and so will the child controller.

Comment: The child controller is never executing. If you check out the child controller, it is just a function that receives the $stateParams and halts at debugger. This never happens.

Comment: see my answer. You need to inject a $scope for the child controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your child state controller is missing a `$scope`, all controllers need an `$scope` in angular.
2. When you go to `edituser`, the `systemadmin` controller will also execute, as well as the `edituser` controller.

**EDIT**

Also, you need to define your parameter with curly braces in your route definitions, not with colons, that's `ng-route` syntax not `ui.router`:

`{ url: '/edit/{selectedUser}' }`

Another thing which is suspect you may be missing out, as I have many times, is that the view of your parent state needs to have a `ui-view` itself, [see this working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBanwXtRLBln1xzyFkS0?p=preview).

Comment: I added scope to the child controller. This did not correct that it is not instantiating. If I make it not a child, I hit the debugger.

Comment: Are you passing parameters to the child state, because in the route definitions you've explicitly stated you need a `selecteduser` parameter.

Comment: I am typing this into my address bar: http://localhost:50556/#/systemadmin/edit/TestUser. Is there something I need to be doing in the parent controller to pass this onto the child?

Comment: not really, you should be able to access the parameter in teh child controller by using `$stateParams.selecteduser`.

Comment: @LRFalk01 see my edit(s) and the plunk I've provided.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the ui-view that fixed it. I spent all afternoon trying to figure this out. Thank you.